# Using similar_text and strpos together

Tags: php

I want to create a simple search engine that looks for key words in a users input. I know I can use strpos to check if a word exists in the string. However, I want the users to be able to spell the word wrong. For example,

```
$userInput = "What year did George Washingtin become president?";
$key_word = "Washington";
someFuntion($userInput, $key_word, $percent);
if($percent > .95){
$user_searched_washington = True;
}
```

Is there any php function that does this, or do you have suggestions on how to create a function that does?

Comment: I would run it through a spell checker first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to leverage the [levenshtein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) functionality in PHP's standard library. See here for some examples in the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php

However, this might become a very expensive calculation when your list of possible keywords grows.

EDIT: a minimum viable example:

```
<?php

$myInput = 'persident';
$possibleKeywords = ['tyrant', 'president', 'king', 'royal'];
$scores = [];

foreach ($possibleKeywords as $keyword) {
    $scores[] = levenshtein($myInput, $keyword);
}

echo $possibleKeywords[array_search(min($scores), $scores)];
// prints: "president"
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I came up with based on your title (using both `strpos` and `similar_text`), which should hopefully be enough to get you started. This allows for both single word searches in addition to phrases and ignores punctuation:

```
function search($haystack, $needle) {
    // remove punctuation
    $haystack = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/', '', $haystack);

    // look for exact match
    if (stripos($haystack, $needle)) {
        return true;
    }

    // look for similar match
    $words = explode(' ', $haystack);
    $total_words = count($words);
    $total_search_words = count(explode(' ', $needle));
    for ($i = 0; $i < $total_words; $i++) {
        // make sure the number of words we're searching for
        // don't exceed the number of words remaining
        if (($total_words - $i) < $total_search_words) {
            break;
        }

        // compare x-number of words at a time
        $temp = implode(' ', array_slice($words, $i, $total_search_words));
        $percent = 0;
        similar_text($needle, $temp, $percent);
        if ($percent >= 80) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

$text = "What year did George Washingtin become president?";
$keyword = "Washington";

if (search($text, $keyword)) {
    echo 'looks like a match!';
}
```