# PHP, check if string is similar to another string

Tags: php

Is there a way to check if two strings are similar in PHP?

Say I have the text "rental car", I want "car rental" to be viewed as similar to "rental car".

Or another example, "DS Nintendo" should be similar to "blabla Nintendo DS 4051".

similar_text does not work with the example above. In order to accept it as similar the bar for % would have to be set very low. "DS Nintendo" and "Nintendo DS" would be easy to compare, but now but take this for example. "DS Nintendo", "blabla 352532 1qwd0gs Nintendo 03532 DS". That percentage will be very low.

Comment: I've tried to copy-paste your question in Google. This was the first result, maybe it can help you: http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php

Comment: @KoenHollander Ahh! You beat me to it. :)

Comment: Still I don't understand why lmgtfy is not allowed here :)

Comment: I'm aware of that function, was mostly looking for something that would return true or false.

Comment: @Lithicas Maybe you can create a algorithm that returns false when its like 10% and try when its above *%

Comment: have a look at the [levenshtein algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php)

Comment: @KoenHollander This works for simple strings, but take this for example. "DS Nintendo", "blabla 352532 1qwd0gs Nintendo 03532 DS". That percentage will be very low. And setting the accepted % that low would add in a bunch of results I'm not looking for.

Comment: You need to define what *similar* means in your case. Your examples don't have any characters in common (which is what most of the built-in string comparison functions use as a base). Do you mean you want all of the separate *words* in string A to match string B? If you're only looking for a boolean result, you need to provide an example border between a positive and negative match

Answer (score 5):

You can check out array_intersect I guess:

```
$master=explode(" ", "DS Nintendo");
$test=explode(" ", "blabla Nintendo DS 4051");

$result = array_intersect($master, $test);

if(count($master)===count($result))
{
    echo 'yay!';
}
```

Comment: Cheers, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: That is great use of a built in PHP function :) - I love it

Answer (score 3):

ill suggest you use similar_text, the native function from php.

```
int similar_text ( string $first , string $second [, float &$percent ] )
```

Example:

```
$sim = similar_text('bafoobar', 'barfoo', $perc);
echo "similarity: $sim ($perc %)\n";
$sim = similar_text('barfoo', 'bafoobar', $perc);
echo "similarity: $sim ($perc %)\n";
```

Comment: I'm aware of it's existence. I was more looking for something that returned true or false. Not a percentage.

Comment: Do you have a source? It looks like you 'stole' it from the PHP Documentation

Comment: Sure, but with percentage, you can define how much you consider close from. So, consider a example like if result >= 60% than is true otherwise, is false ;)

Comment: @CristianoPerdigão Sure that works for simple strings, but take this for example. "DS Nintendo", "blabla 352532 1qwd0gs Nintendo 03532 DS". That percentage will be very low.

Comment: So, in this case, you are not looking for a similar strings. I think you are looking for function to find that words on string. Something like $a = 'How are you?'; if (strpos($a, 'are') !== false) {  echo 'true'; } and (int additional) you can use the similar_text() to set percentage to.

Comment: i saw this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40290873/using-similar-text-and-strpos-together

Comment: @Lithicas it's hard to guess what would make the strings "similar" for you enough, therefore something "true/false" out of the box doesn't really make sense if it's not identity, or occurance of (key)words, you could wrap this in a little custom function something like: `function bool_similar_text($s1, $s2, $how_much = 60) { similar_text($s1, $s2, $p); return $p >= $how_much; }`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function **similar_text**:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php

Or the **levenshtein** function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php

For similar (sound) words, exists the **metaphone** function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.metaphone.php

Perhaps you can use a combination of those functions to get a more accurate result.